# Calculating time difference between events in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming I have a table with the following structure :

[image: MySQL Table Structure]

How would I calculate the time difference between events `LOGIN` and `LOGOUT` for specific users? I want to get an aggregate of the session times each user had(so an aggregate of the times between each `LOGIN` and `LOGOUT` sessions). I am aware `datediff` can be used but i'm not sure about the syntax and how I would be able to use it with multiple users

The final out put would be something like :

```
+-------------+-------------------------+
| agent       | Total Session Time      |
+-------------+-------------------------+
| User - 194  | 00:30:00                |
| User - 195  | 00:40:00                |
+-------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: It would be much easier if you just made the time field an int field, and stored `time()` in it. Then you just subtract the time on logout from the time on login, and you have the number of seconds of the session.

Comment: @Kyle Unfortunately I can't do that so this is my only option.

Comment: @Kyle That may be "easy" for this specific calculation, but using unix timestamps in MySQL for fields that should be datetime/timestamps fields can be problematic in other ways if you will be querying the field using other date aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

My version outputs only difference between last logout and login actions:

```
select t1.agent, timediff(t2.lot, t1.lit) 
from (select agent, max(time) lit 
      from log where event = 'login' group by 1) as t1 
  join (select agent, max(time) lot 
        from log where event = 'logout' group by 1) as t2 
  on t1.agent = t2.agent 
group by 1;
```

I used the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `agent` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event` enum('login','logout') DEFAULT NULL
)
```

**Example data and output**

Data:

```
+---------------------+-------+--------+
| time                | agent | event  |
+---------------------+-------+--------+
| 2015-07-23 15:40:18 | u1    | login  |
| 2015-07-23 14:40:24 | u2    | login  |
| 2015-07-23 16:40:34 | u1    | logout |
| 2015-07-23 16:40:39 | u2    | logout |
| 2015-07-23 16:44:19 | u2    | login  |
| 2015-07-23 16:46:25 | u2    | logout |
+---------------------+-------+--------+
```

Result of select:

```
+-------+--------------------------+
| agent | timediff(t2.lot, t1.lit) |
+-------+--------------------------+
| u1    | 01:00:16                 |
| u2    | 00:02:06                 |
+-------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: what happens if an user hasn't yet to log out, or logged in twice? (maybe the first time he just left, allowing the session to expire)

Comment: This is close but I can't use the last session only I need all the session aggregates as I'm building user statistics. I guess I'll probably have to do it manually with `PHP`.

Comment: @STTLCU yes, your remarks are correct, my answer only gives an idea. It does not handle corner cases.

Comment: Yes :) It's just a subtle nudge to whoever is going to copy-paste this in the future.